# Display all of specific POI in a country - google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, point-of-interest

I am working on a project which happens to collaborate with google maps. I would like to display all of business POI in one country.
I guess this is not enough:

```
 {
  featureType: "poi.business",
  elementType: "labels",
  stylers: [
   { visibility: "on" }
  ]
 }
```

It would be better to build up a function which counts the length of all the POI then displays them on the map, but I am quite new with the Google Maps api. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
            var title = [];
            var first = ""; 

            /* Where markers[i] is already provided */
            for( var j in markers[i]["marker"] ) 
            {
                if( !first )
                {
                    first = j;
                }
                if( markers[i]["marker"][j]["name2"] )
                {
                    title.push(markers[i]["marker"][j]["name2"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    title.push(markers[i]["marker"][j]["name"]);
                }
            }
```

Then I call the map with the markers :D 
Thanks a lot people

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro)

You will get a JSON response in when you can use to populate your map

Comment: I didn't know there was a whole API for this.
Perfect. The documentation is chaotically huge.
Thanks, I'll get back to you.